Let's get critical: May 2013 Site Self-Evaluation
We all love Bitcoin Stack Exchange, but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.
The Site Self-Evaluation review queue is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.
Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? Post an answer below to share your thoughts and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

I see one problem in this site: there is more and more spam messages and advertisement. I think that such things should be deleted, not downvoted and closed.

Final Results

I ran out of space while synchronizing, how do I get my private keys & find my balance?
Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 1)

Can someone saturate the network?
Net Score: 5 (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

Is Namecoin actually being used for anything significant?
Net Score: 6 (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

Why do the creators of ASICs not just keep them for themselves?
Net Score: 7 (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

How does vanitygen calculate difficulty?
Net Score: 5 (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

Is it possible for the network to stop finding valid blocks?
Net Score: 7 (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

How can I measure the "health" of Bitcoin?
Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)

How to configure CGMiner with CPU?
Net Score: 5 (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

What's the alternative to bitcoins that can be profitably mined by beginner?
Net Score: -3 (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 3)

Benefits of bitcoin as national currency?
Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)


